# Jupyter Notebooks, startup and stopping

Tags: localhost, jupyter-notebook

When I started my Jupyter Notebook with, for example,

```
 > jupyter notebook  &
```

my browser would fire up automatically, and I could then choose my notebook to start working. This has stopped happening, and I now have a message such as:

```
execution error: "http://localhost:8889/tree?token=fd657c...9326aca6ed" doesn’t understand the “open location” message. (-1708)
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: same thing happening to me. Did you fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, you could do this:

```
$ jupyter-notebook --browser="chrome" .
```

Comment: Had this issue, your command line suggestion works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Updates to the Mac OS seems to have caused problems. This thread is helpful, [Jupyter Notebook issues](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2438).

You can set the browser explicitly in ".jupyter_notebook_config.py":

```
c.NotebookApp.browser = u'chrome'
```

And that has solved the error for some. It will probably be addressed in a future update if you can put up with the error for now.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. I have no idea though if I have a .jupyter_notebook_config.py file, and if so, where it'd be (!!)

Comment: it will be in a hidden folder called .jupyter, probably in your home directory. If not you can create one with   $ jupyter notebook --generate-config